# Does the word scalar still apply if it's not a vector?

Tags: definition

If I take the value of something, say $50$g and I multiply that value by something else, so perhaps $50\text{g} \times 3$ what would that $3$ be called? It acts like a scalar but I'm not sure that definition applies when we're not talking about vectors.

Sorry if this isn't really maths. I'm not sure where else to ask this.

Comment: Yes, you can call that "scalar" to remark is an element of some field. Yet in most "common life" applications, "number" does the work much simpler for almost all.

Comment: It could also be called a "multiplier".

Answer (score 1):

It is a scalar, but the term you are looking for may be "factor".

As in "multiply the weight ($50\mathrm g$) by a factor of $3$"